# Library dexedLibs is not used

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio.

In my project settings (exported from eclipse) appears:

*Library 'dexedLibs' is not used*

I must add it to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dexedLibs is an internal intermediary folder used by Eclipse. You should not have to do anything with it.

Gradle doesn't use pre-dexing yet, but it'll come and when it does the location will be different than the Eclipse project.